# Saving the uploaded file to a particular location with a particular name using javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi i have a plain html page which will contain one form with file upload option through multipart. Now my requirement is i need help to move that uploaded file to a particular location and want to save with a particular name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to save the file server-side or client-side ?

Comment: In my project i have one folder let's say X, i want to upload that file to X folder with name of let's say Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you're not using `node.js`. If I'm right, it's not possible. JS will execute in browser and can't do anything on server.

If you want to upload file, you need some server-side language like PHP. There are many examples available, just google it.

Answer (score 0):

Use FileSaver.js. It's cross-browsers and very simple to use : https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Comment: I want to save data of uploaded file then?